# how to have multiple instance of the same servlet on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I write a servlet and this servlet must to be instanced many times in the same server.
How to do that ?
Is that some alias or parameter to define many "web servers" from the same servlet (with different parameters)

Thanks for your help

Thierry Vorms

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The servlet specification dictates that only one instance of a servlet class should exist.

But it would be wrong to do otherwise. Don't use instance-variables in servlets. If you needs something like that - use session or request attributes

Answer (score 1):

your question isn't terribly well worded, but will try and interpolate to see if I can figure out what you mean.

1. if you mean have the same class used as many servlets - you can do this. e.g you could have a servlet class called ColorServlet, and an init param that tells it what color to serve up. Then you can have this referenced twice in the same web.xml file with two different servlet-mapping entries to two url patterns, e.g /myapp/color/blue and /myapp/color/red. You use an init-param section in the XML to set startup parameters for your servlet Have a look [Here](http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/)
2. if you mean expose additional HTTP listeners on different ports - yup - this is also do-able, just have more 'connector' elements in your server.xml - they will all share your code, so you can serve the same servlet from multiple 'servers'

Answer (score 0):

A Web application can have servlet's with different names and point to the same class. I think this is what you were asking.

Answer (score -1):

Since Servlet 3.0 specification [ServletContext](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.0/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) class has multiple versions of [addServlet](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.0/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) method. This API can programmatically add multiple instances of the same servlet. Some libraries use this trick, usually implementing adding servlets in [ServletContainerInitializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) interface.
For example, RestEasy library does it in [this class](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/main/resteasy-servlet-initializer/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/servlet/ResteasyServletInitializer.java).